# Console undefined after switching frames IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using the console to play around with some html inside of IE9, after switching to a new frame I am not getting this error whenever I type something into the javascript console

```
>> cd(fraMain) 
Current window: SearchResults 

>> alert("Hello") 

"'__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE' is undefined"
```

Why is this happening to me, and what can I do to get my `'__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE` redefined?